# Calculate one hour difference between two dates

Tags: apache-pig

```
dataset = LOAD '/user/cloudera/project/answers.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS ( qid:chararray , i:chararray , qs:int, qt:long, tags:chararray, qvc:chararray , qac:int , aid:chararray, j:chararray, as:int, at:long); 
onedate = FOREACH dataset GENERATE ToDate(qt*1000) as qstntime , ToDate(at*1000) as anstime,tags;
difftime = FILTER onedate by GetHour(qstntime)-GetHour(anstime)==1;
dump difftime;
```

Output

```
(2009-02-18T17:37:11.000-08:00,2009-04-17T16:22:01.000-07:00,"ctags") 
(2009-02-18T20:31:17.000-08:00,2009-02-19T19:29:40.000-08:00,"iphone")
(2009-02-18T22:11:11.000-08:00,2009-03-20T21:58:21.000-07:00,"php")
(2009-02-18T23:36:58.000-08:00,2009-02-19T22:18:10.000-08:00,"sqlserver") 
(2009-02-19T01:05:39.000-08:00,2009-02-20T00:44:53.000-08:00,"python")
```

which is wrong output. it is calculating subtraction only for hours. While subtracting it has to consider month and year also.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using GetHours, you are only comparing hours and hence the incorrect result. Instead use [HoursBetween](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#hours-between) which compares the entire datetime object.It returns the number of hours between two DateTime objects.

```
difftime = FILTER onedate by (HoursBetween(qstntime,anstime) == 1);
```

Comment: Hope this gonna fix. Thanks